# Adjusting Lightness using ColorMatrix

Tags: android, colormatrix, colormatrixfilter

I'm trying to adjust the lightness of an image (You can see this option in Photoshop when trying to adjust the Hue, also lightness and brightness are two different features) using ColorMatrix but am lost on which values to change to achive this.

Currently I'm able to change the Hue using this code

```
public static void adjustHue(ColorMatrix cm, float value)
    {
        value = cleanValue(value, 180f) / 180f * (float) Math.PI;
        if (value == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(value);
        float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(value);
        float lumR = 0.213f;
        float lumG = 0.715f;
        float lumB = 0.072f;
        float[] mat = new float[]
        { 
                lumR + cosVal * (1 - lumR) + sinVal * (-lumR), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (-lumG), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (1 - lumB), 0, 0, 
                lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (0.143f), lumG + cosVal * (1 - lumG) + sinVal * (0.140f), lumB + cosVal * (-lumB) + sinVal * (-0.283f), 0, 0,
                lumR + cosVal * (-lumR) + sinVal * (-(1 - lumR)), lumG + cosVal * (-lumG) + sinVal * (lumG), lumB + cosVal * (1 - lumB) + sinVal * (lumB), 0, 0, 
                0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 
                0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f };
        cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
    }
```

I  want to understand on how to use the colormatrix to change the lightness in the same way. If there is any other way of achieving this, I'm open for solutions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok..So I finally figured this out.

Lightness can be adjusted using the PorterDuffColorFilter Class

Here's the method that I'm using

```
public static PorterDuffColorFilter applyLightness(int progress) {

    if(progress>0)
    {
        int value = (int) progress*255/100;
        return new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 255, 255, 255), Mode.SRC_OVER);
    } else {
        int value = (int) (progress*-1)*255/100;
        return new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 0, 0, 0), Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }

}
```

The value of progress is from -100 (dark) to 100(bright)

Just pass the values as in photoshop to this method. The filter that you get can be used with paint and canvas.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: how to use this method ??

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to change lightness

```
public static void adjustLightness(ColorMatrix cm, float value)
{
    value = cleanValue(value, 100);
    if (value == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    float[] mat = new float[]
            {
                    1,0,0,0,value,
                    0,1,0,0,value,
                    0,0,1,0,value,
                    0,0,0,1,0,
                    0,0,0,0,1
            };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
}

//Helper method
protected static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit)
{
    return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
}
```

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html), but I'd recommend you to use [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis) because of it's speed.

Comment: You've got one too many rows in your input array here. ColorMatrix is a 4x5 matrix