# Enhancing ImageView brightness programmatically

Tags: android, optimization, android-imageview

I have an android app in which I am increasing brightness of image with the code below. But this is very slow so does anyone knows a fast way to enhance image brightness of an imageview in android. Keep in mind this is improving imageview brightness not screen brightness

```
 public static Bitmap doBrightness(Bitmap src, int value) {
    //Log.e("Brightness", "Changing brightnhjh");

    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmout = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i=i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j=j++) {
            pixel = src.getPixel(i, j);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            G = Color.green(pixel);
            B = Color.blue(pixel);
            R += value;
            if (R > 255) {
                R = 255;
            } else if (R < 0) {
                R = 0;
            }
            G += value;
            if (G > 255) {
                G = 255;
            } else if (G < 0) {
                G = 0;
            }
            B += value;
            if (B > 255) {
                B = 255;
            } else if (B < 0) {
                B = 0;
            }
            bmout.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
    return bmout;

}
```

this is the imageview

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(doBrightness(image, 40));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got a work around for this issue i made the image brighter and then shown it in an imageview. The code i used is given below:

```
foto.setColorFilter(brightIt(100));//foto is my ImageView
//and below is the brightIt func
public static ColorMatrixColorFilter brightIt(int fb) {
ColorMatrix cmB = new ColorMatrix();
cmB.set(new float[] { 
    1, 0, 0, 0, fb,
    0, 1, 0, 0, fb,
    0, 0, 1, 0, fb,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0   });

ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.set(cmB);
//Canvas c = new Canvas(b2);
//Paint paint = new Paint();
ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
//paint.setColorFilter(f);   
return f;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a color matrix, setting it, then creating another color matrix, and setting it using the matrix you just set?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following code to enhance the image :

```
public static Bitmap enhanceImage(Bitmap mBitmap, float contrast, float brightness) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
        {
            contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
            0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
            0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0
        });
    Bitmap mEnhancedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap
        .getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mEnhancedBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    return mEnhancedBitmap;
}
```

note :
contrast : 0 to 10
brightness : -255 to 255

Answer (score 2):

I can't exactly remember where i got this from but i use this (with negative value to get something darker, put some positive value to get something bright)

```
drawable.setColorFilter(applyLightness(-30));


public static PorterDuffColorFilter applyLightness(int progress)
{
    if (progress > 0)
    {
        int value = (int) progress * 255 / 100;
        return new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 255, 255, 255), Mode.SRC_OVER);
    }
    else
    {
        int value = (int) (progress * -1) * 255 / 100;
        return new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 0, 0, 0), Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
```

edit : found where i took this from : [Adjusting Lightness using ColorMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175088/adjusting-lightness-using-colormatrix)

Comment: it does bright but does not contact the overall RGB ratio and the image looks unreal edited.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didnt work for me as I had an imageview with image set using bitmap.
So this is what it worked:

```
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter brightness(float value) {
        ColorMatrix cmB = new ColorMatrix();
        cmB.set(new float[]{
                1, 0, 0, 0, value,
                0, 1, 0, 0, value,
                0, 0, 1, 0, value,
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0});
        return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cmB);
    }
```

Have a seek bar with controls the brightness.Its range is from -255 to 255.

```
 sbBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(fromUser){
                    photoFilterView.getSource().setColorFilter(brightness(progress));

               /*     Filter brightness=new Filter();
                    brightness.addSubFilter(new BrightnessSubFilter(progress));

                    Bitmap ouputImage = brightness.processFilter(bm);
                    photoFilterView.getSource().setImageBitmap(ouputImage);*/
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sbBrightness.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },1000);

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps some.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a semi-transparent view on top of your ImageView. How: a FrameView with two children, the 1st one is the ImageView and the 2nd is a View (just View) with a semi-transparent background. Then you will have to modify the background opacity programmatically.