# increase or decrease image brightness works very slow using seekbar

Tags: android

I'm using brightness code using seek bar.It is taking very long time to show the brightness in imageview.

Below I have posted the code :

**BrightActivity.java:**

```
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class BrightActivity extends Activity {


    SeekBar seekbarbrightness;

    Bitmap largeIcon;

    ImageView ivDisImage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bright_activity);



        seekbarbrightness = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        ivDisImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lhota);



        seekbarbrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Bitmap bitmap=doBrightness(largeIcon, progress);
                ivDisImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ivDisImage.setColorFilter(brightIt(100));

            }
        });


    }


    public static Bitmap doBrightness(Bitmap src, int value) {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // scan through all pixels
        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);

                // increase/decrease each channel
                R += value;
                if(R > 255) { R = 255; }
                else if(R < 0) { R = 0; }

                G += value;
                if(G > 255) { G = 255; }
                else if(G < 0) { G = 0; }

                B += value;
                if(B > 255) { B = 255; }
                else if(B < 0) { B = 0; }

                // apply new pixel color to output bitmap
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }

        // return final image
        return bmOut;
    }

    public static ColorMatrixColorFilter brightIt(int fb) {
        ColorMatrix cmB = new ColorMatrix();
        cmB.set(new float[] {
                1, 0, 0, 0, fb,
                0, 1, 0, 0, fb,
                0, 0, 1, 0, fb,
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0   });

        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.set(cmB);
//Canvas c = new Canvas(b2);
//Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
//paint.setColorFilter(f);
        return f;
    }



}
```

**bright_activity.java:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Brightness"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lhota" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone know how to increase and decrease brightness of image faster using seekbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya check this http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.in/2013/07/set-brightness-of-imageincreasedecrease.html. only the image not the screen.

Comment: Got the point . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891520/how-to-programmatically-change-contrast-of-a-bitmap-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to put an overlay of black color on the imageView and then just map  the transparency of the overlay with seekbar easy and time saving solution.

or You can just use the following code to enhance the brightness of bitmap

```
/**
 * 
 * @param bmp input bitmap
 * @param contrast 0..10 1 is default
 * @param brightness -255..255 0 is default
 * @return new bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness)
{
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });

    Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

    return ret;
}
```

Thanks to this answer [change the contrast and brightness of the bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891520/how-to-programmatically-change-contrast-of-a-bitmap-in-android/17887577#17887577)

Comment: so, we can't get more brighter picture than the original one is ?

Comment: more brighter picture ?? what do you mean by that? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ArsenSench just added a method to enhance the contrast and brightness of the bitmap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507139/enhancing-imageview-brightness-programmatically

Comment: now it's clear. But for me this is working brightness 0-10 and contrast -255 255 . don't know why

Comment: @ArsenSench it is working fine follow the doc of method written above :)

Comment: @rana_sadam, it's working fine if i change the range of values for contrast and brightness.