# Issue applying ColorFilter on image view

Tags: android, imageview, colorfilter

I am working on image filter app and facing an issue.
So I want to know how to apply colour, saturation and brightness on image view?
(please consider that my image view have only one flat color)

For Color:

```
 public void setImageColor(int color) {
        image.setColorFilter(color);
    }
```

For Saturation:

```
 public void setSaturationBitmap(int saturation) {
        image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        image.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = image.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.reset();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(satur);
        paint.setColorFilter(image.getColorFilter());
        paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, matrix, paint);
        image.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Code is necessary. Share it.

Comment: You may want to extend the ImageView, and override `onDraw` method, and after calling `super.onDraw()` apply your filter

Comment: final int semiTransparentGrey = Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185);
  drawable.setColorFilter(semiTransparentGrey, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Comment: you can see my edited quetion @Piyush

Comment: In my case saturation working proper but when I change the color than after I cannot apply saturation @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the bitmap and use it in Image view:

follow this post on SOF:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35055244/7147289

Comment: answer with the link to another answer could never be good. Either use a comment, or write a full answer.